# RTX 2080 eGPU and Cuda Tensorflow on MacBook Pro

Tags: 18.10, cuda, macbook-pro, tensorflow

I cant install Ubuntu on my MacBook Pro 2018, QEMU KVM, VMware and Parallels doesn't support Thunderbolt3.
There are no Nvidia drivers for RTX on the Mac and TensorFlow doesn't support GPUs on macOS anyway.

What the is the best way to solve it?